# How was the door to Bag End able to be green?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

In *The Hobbit* (and *The Lord of the Rings*) the door to Bag End is described as green. I'm curious to know how this was achieved; is outdoor weather proof paint easily made, and a technology that would be reasonable to exist in the world setting? Are there paint-like substances that can be used to colour wood? Are some woods naturally green?

Comment: Are you asking if we can produce green paint with the technology available in Shire? Because real world justifications are almost always off topic and this is why you are getting downvotes.

Comment: Ok, so - just to be sure I have this striaght in my head - given orcs, balrogs, dragons, ents, elves, hobbits, dwarves, giant talking eagles, seeing stones, wizards, werebears, barrow wrights, rings of power, darklords and wraiths . . . your problem is paint?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier - Did you check their username? :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, my question wasn't clear in retrospect, it was how is durable paint created with Shire technologies. Pretty much everything else in the Shire is relatively easy to create, but a real paint, that isn't made from crushed beatles or tree-bark (which seems impractical) or has to be re-applied every week (which also seems impractical) is a pretty large barrier to overcome. Dragons, dwaves, rings of power etc. are all explained by the interaction of eru, ainur, maiar etc. but I can't see them creating paint for a door in the Shire.

Comment: @painter: Maybe paint is too. Maybe the secret to the durability of Elven wrought goods is the application of a good layer of lead paint. Maybe there's a hard working dwarf somewhere churning out gallons of matt and gloss paints in a range of colours, maybe it's a function of one of the rings of power ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ who knows?

Comment: I hear all those [alabaster white statues](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/10/29/the-myth-of-whiteness-in-classical-sculpture) from ancient Greece and Rome *used to be painted in full colour.*  It's worn off now, approximately 2000 years later, but I sincerely doubt they needed to reapply that stuff every week, back in the day.  I think your expectations of "paint technology" in a "Shire-like" society are somewhat under the mark.

Comment: @Painter  A lot of other stuff in the Shire is less easy to understand than paint.  Bilbo's mantlepiece clock, for example.  It wasprobably made by Dwarves and paid for by selling food to them.

Comment: Paint doesn’t have to be durable if you re-apply it once a year or every six months or whatever.

Comment: @Steve-O Actually classical sculptures didn’t lose all of their paint through natural wear, they were deliberately “cleaned” and bleached during a somewhat racist period in Europe.

Comment: a little history: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint#History

Comment: I'd like to point out in An Unexpected Journey Bilbo says the door was painted "a week ago", and the paint appears to already be coming off, so.. I don't think weatherproof paint was of concern to Bilbo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the text shows, Bilbo painted his door every now and then. He had painted it shortly before Gandalf brought the gaggle of Dwarves to recruit him!

There is an EASY way to make green paint.

Take a chunk of copper. Let it sit in the weather for a while. A decade or two should suffice.

Now scrape of the green stuff. You have acquired Verdigris!
If you prefer a more Aqua shade, use the shortcut and soak the copper in vinegar.
Fortunately, the local branches of the EPA, FDA and OSHA are still under construction, so we need not worry about this green stuff being *quite* poisonous. (as a fringe benefit, it *does* help protect your wooden door from fungus and rot and insects)

Now just dry, then mix the Verdigris with your chosen oil or lacquer based paint.

Due to the deficiencies of outdoor paints using medieval era chemistry, you may need to make the painting an annual ritual.

Answer (score 18):

### It was painted green

> It had a perfectly round door like a porthole, "painted green", with a shiny yellow brass knob in the exact middle.
> <sub>The Hobbit - Chapter 1: An Unexpected Party</sub>

As stated in the opening of The Hobbit the door was painted green.

Bilbo paints the door from time to time, in fact it was painted just a week before the Dwarves' arrival:

> "Pardon me," he said, "if I have overheard words that you were saying. I don't pretend to understand what you are talking about, or your reference to burglars, but I think I am right in believing" (this is what he called being on his dignity) "that you think I am no good. I will show you. I have no signs on my door-it was painted a week ago-, and I am quite sure you have come to the wrong house.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

The Elves also had paint, as did the people of Bree and the Men of Rohan:

> By it were moored many Boats and Barges. Some were brightly painted, and shone with silver and gold and green, but most were either white or grey.
> <sub>The Fellowship of the Ring: Book II, Chapter 8: Farewell to Lorien</sub>

> Over the doors was painted in white letters: THE PRANCING PONY: by BARLIMAN BUTTERBUR
> <sub>The Fellowship of the Ring: Book 1, Chapter 9, At the sign of the Prancing Pony</sub>

> In their hands were tall spears of ash, painted shields were slung at their backs, long swords were at their belts, their burnished skirts of mail hung down upon their knees.
> <sub>The Two Towers: Chapter 2, The Riders of Rohan</sub>

Both Sauron and Saruman painted parts of their orcs with their respective symbols, the red eye and the white hand:

> They had a red eye painted on their shields.
> <sub>The Two Towers, Book III, Chapter 3: The Uruk-hai</sub>

> Suddenly a tall pillar loomed up before them. It was black; and set upon it was a great stone, carved and painted in the likeness of a long White Hand.
> <sub>ibid, Book III, Chapter 8: The Road to Isengard</sub>

There were even mentions of graffiti performed by the orcs:

> The brief glow fell upon a huge setting figure, still and solemn of the great kings of Argonath. The years had gnawed it, and violent hands had maimed it. Its head was gone, and in its place was set in mockery a round rough-hewn stone, rudely painted by savage hands in the likeness of a grinning face with one large red eye in the midst of its forehead.
> <sub>ibid, Book IV, Chapter 7: Journey to the Cross-Roads</sub>